# Could not find "store" in the context of Connect()

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am writing mobile app in React Native. I am trying to use Redux to simply store a textfield input. I have followed multiple guides but I still get this error.

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(CreateSearch)".
```

In `App.js` create a store and a reducer:

```
const initialState = {
name: ''
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'CHANGE_NAME':
            return{name:'Alex'}
    }
    return state;
};

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
```

Then wrap the `CreateSearch` component in a provider:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <CreateSearch/>
        </Provider>
      );
  }
}
```

Finally in the `createSearch` I made the functions `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. It also connects.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    name:state.name
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    changeName: () => dispatch({type:'CHANGE_NAME'})
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateSearch);
```

Because I have tried to fix this the last few days I am really frustrated... I know this has been asked multiple times but I couldn't find an answer that worked. I hope you can help.

Comment: It seems that you are not exporting your store, and it is not clear where it is imported in the file the class App belongs to

Comment: Do I just add 'export store'? Also what exactly do I have to import?

App.js imports createStore and provider.
createSearch imports connect.

Comment: The the code snippet where you have the App component defined, can you add where does the "store" variable comes from? if it comes from another module, can you add that one too?